# Omit specific SQL result from SELECT query

Tags: php, sql, select

I am not great with SQL syntax and from my research of this issue I've been able to stumble on example of excluding columns from database queries, but not actual table results that will be returned.

A php script is running the below SQL query:

```
$query = $db->query("SELECT `team`, `points`, `goalsfor`, `goalsagainst`, `goalsdifference`, `matches`, `wins`, `draws`, `losses` FROM `".TABLE_PREFIX."myleagues_rows` WHERE `league` = {$lid} ORDER BY `points` DESC, `goalsdifference` DESC, `goalsfor` DESC, `goalsagainst` ASC");
```

It then references it again and inserts the data into a formatted HTML table, the next part of the query:

```
while($row = $db->fetch_array($query)) {
        foreach($row as $name => $value) {
            $teams[$row['team']][$name] = $value;
```

[Full link](http://pastebin.com/zVQDxSaV) to the php file in case I am missing important things.

My question, is that there's a row in that table with the team name "Test" that will be returned and inserted into the formatted table. I don't want to remove test team from the database but I do want to exclude it from the formatted table.

Am I best modifying the SQL query? Or is there something on the PHP side of things I can do instead?

Thanks for any advice and please point me in the right direction if I'm looking in the wrong place, I did not write the code (obviously).

Answer (score 0):

You can remove it from the SQL query with a WHERE statement (I'm guessing "team" is the name?):

```
$query = $db->query("SELECT 
    `team`, 
    `points`, 
    `goalsfor`,
    `goalsagainst`, 
    `goalsdifference`, 
    `matches`, 
    `wins`, 
    `draws`, 
    `losses` 
FROM `".TABLE_PREFIX."myleagues_rows` 
WHERE 
    `league` = {$lid} 
    AND `team` != 'test' 
ORDER BY 
    `points` DESC, 
    `goalsdifference` DESC, 
    `goalsfor` DESC, 
    `goalsagainst` ASC");
```

Answer (score 0):

As you've observed, there's two different options here: change the database query or change the PHP that processes the results.

Changing the database query is as simple as adding an additional term in the `WHERE` clause, which might look like this:

```
SELECT
    `team`,
    `points`,
    `goalsfor`,
    `goalsagainst`,
    `goalsdifference`,
    `matches`,
    `wins`,
    `draws`,
    `losses`
FROM
    `{{TABLE_PREFIX}}myleagues_rows`
WHERE
    `league` = {{$lid}} AND
    `team` <> 'Test'
ORDER BY
    `points` DESC,
    `goalsdifference` DESC,
    `goalsfor` DESC,
    `goalsagainst` ASC
;
```

Alternatively you can modify the PHP to exclude this team by adding an `if` statement:

```
while($row = $db->fetch_array($query)) {
    if ($row['team'] !== 'Test') {
        foreach($row as $name => $value) {
            $teams[$row['team']][$name] = $value;
        }
    }
}
```

So which one's best? The problem you're going to face is that the code to exclude the "Test" team is going to keep coming up time and again - every time you want to query a list of teams. You probably want to push this code into a higher-level abstraction:

- Rather than making raw queries against the database, why not use some sort of Object-Relational Mapper (ORM) such as [Doctrine](http://www.doctrine-project.org/)? This will make things a lot easier:
  -- excluding the test row becomes one line of code
  -- alternatively you can exclude the test row whenever querying the "team" model
- Alternatively you could push the logic into the database by creating a view that excludes the test row. You can then run your query against the new view rather than the underlying table. This is probably fairly easy to do using your "`TABLE_PREFIX`" mechanism.

While I'm writing, it's worth checking that the `$lid` value you're passing to the database has been properly validated. It's generally considered bad practice to assemble database queries by concatenating strings together as that has the potential to be vulnerable to [SQL Injection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection) attacks. If you don't want to go via the ORM route, then you should definitely consider switching to a database library that accepts [Prepared Statements](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prepared_statement). As a bare minimum you should certainly be making sure that your `$lid` is an integer value in the sort of range that you expect.

Comment: Won't the second example give him all the columns in the "test"-record except any field with the value "Test"? And iit will also ignore any other columns, for other records, containing "Test" and not just the "Test"-team.

Comment: @MagnusEriksson that's a fair criticism - but an app with  few queries often evolves into an app with many queries and it's then potentially too late to go back... It would also avoid the potential SQLi vector via `$lid`.

Comment: Fair enough. I did remove my comment since it was very much opinion based and totally situation based. :)